# Does this kind of data/field in this table needs normalization in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have this **uom** table in MYSQL:

| id | uom |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | piece |
| 2 | dozen |
| 3 | set |

and this **products** table in MYSQL:

| id | itemNo | title | uom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19421 | test1 | 1:1:10.00,3:1:56.17 |
| 2 | 7878 | test2 | 1:1:24.33 |
| 3 | 123456 | test3 | 2:12:63.22,3:1:14.00 |
| 4 | 666565 | test4 | 1:1:10.00,2:12:20.00,3:1:30.00 |

Does this **products** table needs normalization? Some people said that this table doesn't have multi-value field/data... Is that correct? The **products** table in short, has name, title and a uom column of a product. Uom column has unit of storage, quantity package, and price based on the unit. That means each product has different unit and prices based on the unit.

For example, the test4 product has three units  `1:1:10.00`,`2:12:20.00`,`3:1:30.00`. We'll take the first unit, as an example: `1:1:10.00`.

- 1st number is the id of the unit in the **units** table
- 2nd number is the quantity package
- 3rd number is the price

So, `1:1:10.00` is one unit. `2:12:20.00` and `3:1:30.00` are different units. So, test4 a total of 3 units.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @mustaccio Question edited

Answer (score 5):

I would vote yes to normalize it. Units of measure, i.e. a `UOM` column, should literally be units of measure, e.g. "meters", "yards", "pounds", "tons" etc. I don't see that at all in the values you're currently storing in it, such as `1:1:10.00`. You even say it yourself, that these are different data points "*3rd number is the price*". Then you should likely have a `Price` column instead. If you want to store just the `ID` of the `UOM` in the `UOM` column, that's fine, but I'd recommend normalizing the other data points appropriately.

By stuffing multiple data points into one column, you hurt the readability, maintainability, and query-ability of that column. It could even affect performance if you need to run functions against that column to parse certain data points from it, especially if those data points are used in predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses) anywhere in your queries.

Comment: Ok, then which normal form should I choose to normalize?

Comment: I second this answer.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey You second this answer?

Comment: @Algo Yes, I agree with J.D.'s answer. You need to break the columns out. It's how I would have answered the question, had he not already done so.

Comment: @Algo I personally wouldn't focus on particular levels of normal form. While good in theory, sometimes it's simpler in practice to just stick to a basic principle of *one-field one-purpose*. So each of those data points, in my mind, should get their own field. Whether that's in the same table or a different table, more so to me depends on if they make logical sense (by relevancy) as part of the same object or not if you think about the concrete form when you instantiate an entity.

Comment: @J.D. How it can be in the same table? Especially, the id is a primary key? Could you please normalize my table above in the same table, so I can see how?

Comment: @Algo I said it depends on the relevancy of the fields. E.g. the `Price` data point can be its own column in the same table, just like your first table, if it's the price of the product. If it's something else like `PricePerUnit` then that could possibly go in the `Units` table along with your other data points (if the price is strongly tied to the type of unit of measure), and the unit of measure name. Otherwise, even the `PricePerUnit` can live in your products table, if the price is strongly dependent on the individual product. So it just depends on relevancy, driven by the business logic.

Comment: @J.D. Ok, I am talking about the second table that has uom in it. So, regarding second table I must split it into 2 tables? I already explained second table it in the post. What do you mean "it just depends on relevancy, driven by the business logic."?

Comment: @Algo I'll update my answer later to give table examples, because comments aren't meant for extended discussion. But my previous comment was referring to your second table also. You said your current `uom` column stores multiple data points, one of those data points being the price. I'm saying you could make that it's own column in your second table instead of storing it in the `uom` column. That's one example where you can normalize within the same table. But yes you'll also need a third table, `UnitOfMeasures`, most likely too.

Comment: @J.D. I have updated my original post for more clarity. Could you please update your answer with a real normalize of my products table above with the 2 ways, within the table itself and with 2 tables?

Answer (score 1):

***Does this table needs normalization?***

Short answer: **yes**.

Slighlty less short answer: normalization is not something a database table "needs", but in some cases (like this one) normalization is highly recommended as it will bring a lot of benefits.

***Some people said that this table doesn't have multi-value field/data... Is that correct?***

It's not correct. Not only does this table have a multi-value column, the values of this multi-value column are entities on themselves, with their own set of values. And unless you're using a column type that is meant to have complex structures as values (say, a JSON column), this kind of column makes overly complicated to manipulate and process its data.

---

Now, the drawback: changing the data structure would be a breaking change, so if this data is read as-is an parsed in a lot of different places, then this would require a lot of changes across a lot of modules, then the benefit could come at a relatively high cost. You need to leverage if the normalization is worth it i.e. if the changes are not that complicated, or if there's risk that keeping the data structure as it is now would eventually make the information unreadable and unmaintenable if/when it grows too big.

Comment: Ok, then which normal form should I choose to normalize?